# Directed graph viewer for commercial use

Tags: windows, gratis, graphs

After unsuccessfully trying to find a stable binary build of [Agl](http://rise4fun.com/Agl/tinyNotepad), Microsoft's Automatic Graph Layout, I'm now looking for

- a free directed graph viewer
- as a library or a standalone viewer
- that can use text based input like the Microsoft example

  ```
  digraph G 
  {
    Hello -> World
  }
  ```
- that allows xcopy installation (i.e. is portable)
- with a very simple UI (just show the graph, perhaps zoom if the graph is very large)
- if standalone viewer: updates the graph when the file is changed
- for Windows (7 and above)
- and is gratis (commercial use allowed)
- and actively maintained

I want to distribute it as part of my installation and I don't want to call another `setup.exe` from my own Setup.

My research:

- [ZGRViewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html) is based on Java, which I definitely want to avoid
- [Graphviz4Net](http://graphviz4net.codeplex.com/) has a dependency to `dot.exe` which cannot be installed
- [idot](https://code.google.com/archive/p/idot/) is again Java-based
- [related SR question without answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25401/1935)
- [related SR question without satisfying answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/dot-graph-viewer)

Comment: Not tested on Windows (I use it on Linux), but did you try [xdot.py](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py)?